# Serialize Dictionary Object Where Keys Are Different

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a dictionary object which has the days of the week as keys. Please can someone advise if there is a way to serialize this object using a Django Serializer.

The example dictionary output looks like this:

```
[{'mon': {'AM': False, 'PM': False}}, {'tue': {'AM': True, 'PM': False}}, {'wed': {'AM': False, 'PM': False}}, {'thu': {'AM': True, 'PM': True}}, {'fri': {'AM': False, 'PM': True}}, {'sat': {'AM': False, 'PM': False}}, {'sun': {'AM': False, 'PM': False}}]
```

The closest I can get is having serializer method fields for each day of the week, but that returns null for every weekday which is not part of the set. I have tried:

```
class SlotSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    AM = serializers.BooleanField()
    PM = serializers.BooleanField()

class SchoolSlotSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    mon = serializers.SerializerMethodField(required=False)
   
    def get_mon(self,obj):
        if obj.get('mon'):
           return SlotSerializer(obj['mon']).data

   #Repeated for each weekday
```

Comment: I think I have found the solution now by creating a "week" object with day being an object to store "AM" and "PM" and then serializing that object using the serializer method field. I am very tired now so will check tomorrow if that is working and post it as an answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it this way:

First I create classes to hold instance of week with the days.

```
class Week(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mon = None
        self.tue = None
        self.wed = None
        self.thu = None
        self.fri = None
        self.sat = None
        self.sun = None

    def add_day(self,day,slots):
        if(day == "mon"):
            self.mon = slots
        elif(day == "tue"):
            self.tue = slots
        elif(day == "wed"):
            self.wed = slots
        elif(day == "thu"):
            self.thu = slots
        elif(day == "fri"):
            self.fri = slots
        elif(day == "sat"):
            self.sat = slots
        elif(day == "tue"):
            self.sun = slots
```

I build the week object as I iterate through the result set returned. Then the serializer is as below:

```
class DaySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    AM = serializers.BooleanField()
    PM = serializers.BooleanField()


class SchoolSlotSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     availability = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     def get_availability(self,obj):
         week = dict()
         week["mon"] = DaySerializer(obj.mon).data
         week["tue"] = DaySerializer(obj.tue).data
         week["wed"] = DaySerializer(obj.wed).data
         week["thu"] = DaySerializer(obj.thu).data
         week["fri"] = DaySerializer(obj.fri).data
         week["sat"] = DaySerializer(obj.sat).data
         week["sun"] = DaySerializer(obj.sun).data
         return week
```

It gives me output as below when called in Insomnia:

```
{
  "availability": {
    "mon": {
      "AM": false,
      "PM": false
    },
    "tue": {
      "AM": true,
      "PM": false
    },
    "wed": {
      "AM": false,
      "PM": false
    },
    "thu": {
      "AM": true,
      "PM": true
    },
    "fri": {
      "AM": false,
      "PM": true
    },
    "sat": {
      "AM": false,
      "PM": false
    },
    "sun": {
      "AM": false,
      "PM": false
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or if there is a better way to do it. It seems to be working for me for now.